# gulp 4 mulitple SPA task composition with series and parallel

Tags: gulp

I have a large build that is composed of multiple sub-projects that are all built from a central set of shared gulp scripts.

Say I want to do this (there are other modules that define the actual tasks for the sub-projects):

```
var apps = [...]; //list of configuration objects for sub-projects in question
function builds() {
  var buildNames = apps.map(function (app) {
    return "release-build-" + app.name;
  });
  return gulp.parallel(buildNames);
}
function tests() {
  var testNames = apps.map(function (app) {
    return "test-" + app.name;
  });
  return gulp.series(testNames);
}
gulp.task("test", tests);
gulp.task("release-build", gulp.series(tests, builds));
```

In gulp 3 I do the following (the code for the `release-build` task follows the same pattern as test):

```
var runSequence = require("run-sequence").use(gulp);
gulp.task("test", function (callback) {
  // Get the test tasks of all children
  var tasks = apps.map(function(app) {
    return "test-" + app.name;
  });
  tasks.push(callback);
  //run tasks sequentially
  return runSequence.apply(null, tasks);
});
```

However when I try to run the new gulp 4 version I get the dreaded:

> The following tasks did not complete 'test'
>   Did you forget to signal async completion?

How can I build my tasks names and pass them to `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()` in gulp 4 like I did with `run-sequence`?

Comment: It looks a bit odd returning `gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel` from those tasks. Have you tried just returning the arrays and then doing `gulp.series(tests, gulp.parallel(builds))`? (I use series and parallel successfully, but have never tried returning a series of tasks from a task, so I am not sure if this will help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `builds` and `tests` functions generate `gulp.parallel()` and `gulp.series()` task compositions. What you want to do is assign **those** generated task compositions as your `test` and `release-build` tasks.

What you are currently doing is to assign the `builds` and `tests` functions **themselves** as your tasks instead of their return values.

You need to actually invoke the `builds` and `tests` functions. So instead of this:

```
gulp.task("test", tests);
gulp.task("release-build", gulp.series(tests, builds));
```

You need to do this:

```
gulp.task("test", tests());
gulp.task("release-build", gulp.series(tests(), builds()));
```

Comment: You are correct. I changed tests and builds to just return a string array and just called them, i.e. gulp.series(tasks()), in my task.